# Autocomplete classes in includes - VS Code PHP Intellisense

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to migrate from PHP Storm to VS Code but there's a little issue that is bothering me.

I'm using PHP Intellisense (tryied Intelliphense too), configured it as the instructions asked (I Have PHP 7.2 and PATH set correctly), my project was opened as a folder.

So here's whats going on (examples):

```
require('incs/DB.php');
$con=new DB(configs,goes,here);
```

DB included and configured to use. If I try to type: "$con->" suggestions appear as they should (GREAT!)

Now another file:

index.php

```
require("config.php");
...more code...
```

If in this file I try to type "$con->" nothing that matters shows up. The suggestions have nothing to do with the class "$con" is using.

So, did I make something wrong or is this a common thing in the extension? Can I only call for suggestions on the same file that "created" the class?

Comment: shouldn't it be `$con = new DB(...)` ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but that's just an example, it's actually "Banco.php"

Comment: Reviews for Intellisense are bad,it`s full of bugs.